# Given a function $f$, prove: if $ f\in BV([a,b])$ then $f$ is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, bounded-variation

prove: if $f\in  BV([a,b])$ then $f$ is a bounded function

i use the method of contrapositive i suppose f is not bounded
such that f goes to ∞ i want to prove that f is not in BV
([a,b]) .

edit

Comment: That is kind of the opposite of what you've been asked to do, but feel free to try it.

Comment: If the function is defined on $[a,b]$ how can you take limit as $x \to \infty $?

Comment: $BV(\Bbb R)$ is full of functions such that $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0$. For instance, $0$.

Comment: Kavi Rama Murthy i edit my question sorry it was a mistake from me and from the website

Comment: Saucy O'Path it is [a,b] thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A direct proof: we denote by $T$ the total variation of $f$. Let $x \in [a,b]$. Then $\{a,x,b\}$ is a partition of $[a,b]$, hence

$S(x):=|f(a)-f(x)|+|f(x)-f(b)| \le T$.

Therefore

$|f(x)| =|f(x)-f(a)+f(a)| \le |f(x)-f(a)|+|f(a)| \le S(x)+|f(a)| \le T+|f(a)|.$

Comment: Why the downvote ?????

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: but why you claim the partition